# Windows 8.1 resize shortcuts in Start menu

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

Is there a way to resize or somehow customize the shortcuts I put in the Start menu?

Like, I have shortcut for Steam.exe on my Desktop, I right click on it, then Pin to Start, and it goes to the start menu, but it is a medium sized icon. I want them to be bigger, and more customizable, like the icon to take the whole space of the tile...

Is there a way to do that? Even if it's with some other program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [OblyTile](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1899865), it will allow you to put customized tiles in the Start menu, with whatever size and icon/picture you want

Answer (score 0):

Rightclick an icon, go to the submenu `Size`, and choose between `small` and `medium`.

This is the only thing you can do with the Metro tile interface in Windows 8.1